# Reactjs/Apollo: TypeError: Object(...)(...).data is undefined

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I've been trying to solve this error for 3 days now and I can't figure out. I keep getting

> TypeError: Object(...)(...).data is undefined
> whenever i try to go to a specific post using it's id. Importing it from db.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import "./post.css";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth";
import DeleteButton from "../components/DeleteButton";
import { FETCH_POST_QUERY } from "../util/graphql";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";


function SinglePost(props) {
    const postId = props.match.params.postId;
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    console.log(postId);
  
    const {
      data: { getPost }
    } = useQuery(FETCH_POST_QUERY, {
      variables: {
        postId
      }
    });

  function deletePostCallback() {
    props.history.push("/");
  }
  let postMarkup;
  if (!getPost) {
    postMarkup = <p>Loading post..</p>;
  } else {
    const {
      id,
      firstname,
      lastname,
      job,
      phone,
      address,
      education,
      workExperience,
    } = getPost;
    //const postKeys = Object.values(getPost.education);

    postMarkup = (
      <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="name-hero">
            <div class="me-img"></div>

            <div class="name-text">
              <h1>
                {firstname} <em>{lastname}</em>
              </h1>
              <p>{address}</p>
              <p>Email soon</p>
              <p>{phone}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right" >
          <div class="inner">
            <section>
              <h1>Employment</h1>
              {workExperience.map((work) => (
                <p key={work.id}>
                  {work.beginDate}--{work.endDate}
                  <em>{work.body}</em>
                </p>
              ))}
            </section>
            <section>
              <h1>Education</h1>
              {education.map((edu) => (
                <p key={edu.id}>
                  {edu.beginDate}--{edu.endDate}
                  <em>{edu.body}</em>
                </p>
              ))}
            </section>
            <section>
              <h1>Technical Skills</h1>
              <ul class="skill-set">
                <li>To be added</li>
              </ul>
            </section>
            <section>
              <h1>References</h1>
              <p>To be Added</p>
            </section>
            <section>
              <h1>Hobbies</h1>
              <ul class="skill-set">
                <li>Faith</li>
                <li>Biblical Studies</li>
                <li>Playing Guitar</li>
                <li>Song Writing</li>
                <li>Health & Nutrition</li>
                <li>Reading</li>
              </ul>
            </section>
            <section>
              <div class="handmade">
                <p>
                  handmade by <em> Anthony Adamski</em>
                </p>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
              }
  return postMarkup;
}
export default SinglePost;
```

I'm using apollo client/server with it's queries.
This is the query I'm using to fetch object from database

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";



export const FETCH_POST_QUERY = gql`
query ($postId: ID!) {
  getPost(postId: $postId) {
    id
    useriD
    firstname
    lastname
    job
    phone
    address
    phone
    education {
      id
      body
      beginDate
      endDate
    }
    workExperience {
      id
      body
      beginDate
      endDate
    }
  }
}
`;
```

this is the result i get from my app

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSQnV.png)

When I try the query in graphQl or apollo studio, the data is fetched without a problem. But when I try it in my app, i get that error. Also whenever I change something about the query, the data is fetched, but when i reload the page, it doesn't work anymore with the same error.

Sorry, i know it's a repeated question but I have been trying to find a solution for past 2 days.

Comment: Check if `data` object contain `getPost`.
Edit: or ideally use useEffect for checking that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first time when query is being executed, `data` will be undefined so when you try to extract `getPost` from undefined, it will show error.

To solve this try to use `loading` state from `useQuery` and extract data after query is executed.

```
function SinglePost(props) {
    const postId = props.match.params.postId;
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    console.log(postId);
  
    const {
      data, loading
    } = useQuery(FETCH_POST_QUERY, {
      variables: {
        postId
      }
    });

  function deletePostCallback() {
    props.history.push("/");
  }
  let postMarkup;
  if (loading) {
    postMarkup = <p>Loading post..</p>;
  } else {
    const {
      id,
      firstname,
      lastname,
      job,
      phone,
      address,
      education,
      workExperience,
    } = data.getPost;
    //const postKeys = Object.values(getPost.education);

    postMarkup = (
      <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="name-hero">
            <div class="me-img"></div>

            <div class="name-text">
              <h1>
                {firstname} <em>{lastname}</em>
              </h1>
              <p>{address}</p>
              <p>Email soon</p>
              <p>{phone}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right" >
          <div class="inner">
            <section>
              <h1>Employment</h1>
              {workExperience.map((work) => (
                <p key={work.id}>
                  {work.beginDate}--{work.endDate}
                  <em>{work.body}</em>
                </p>
              ))}
            </section>
            <section>
              <h1>Education</h1>
              {education.map((edu) => (
                <p key={edu.id}>
                  {edu.beginDate}--{edu.endDate}
                  <em>{edu.body}</em>
                </p>
              ))}
            </section>
            <section>
              <h1>Technical Skills</h1>
              <ul class="skill-set">
                <li>To be added</li>
              </ul>
            </section>
            <section>
              <h1>References</h1>
              <p>To be Added</p>
            </section>
            <section>
              <h1>Hobbies</h1>
              <ul class="skill-set">
                <li>Faith</li>
                <li>Biblical Studies</li>
                <li>Playing Guitar</li>
                <li>Song Writing</li>
                <li>Health & Nutrition</li>
                <li>Reading</li>
              </ul>
            </section>
            <section>
              <div class="handmade">
                <p>
                  handmade by <em> Anthony Adamski</em>
                </p>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
              }
  return postMarkup;
}
export default SinglePost;
```